# Selenium Chrome Driver not working on Pi Zero with error code -4

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver, raspbian

I am trying to set up a script on a new Pi Zero W that was previously working on my Pi 3 B. It seems the hardware may be causing the issue as simply moving the whole operating system etc over to the new pi causes this issue. There are no other changes.

I have tried looking at my Chrome and chrome driver version and matching it up. I am also using the ARMhf version of chrome driver found here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/chromium-chromedriver.

My full code set for the project is here https://github.com/RemakingEden/ski-lodge-tv-slideshow and the relevant code is

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import schedule
import os

url1 = 'http://niseko.nadare.info/'
url2 = 'https://www.windy.com/?43.044,141.348,5,i:pressure,p:off'
url3 = 'https://www.niseko.ne.jp/en/niseko-lift-status/'
intervalAmount = 45
chromeDriverLocation = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver"
timeToSwitch = "09:00"
vlcPlaylistDirectory = "/home/pi/snowFilms"

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--kiosk")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverLocation, 
chrome_options=options)
```

As this works on the Pi 3 B I would expect it to work on the Zero however on the Zero I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python/ski-lodge-tv-slideshow/skiLodge.py", line 24, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverLocation, chrome_options=options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -4
```

Selenium is version 3.141.0

Chromium is 65.0.3325.181

Chromedriver is 65.0.3325.181

I have looked everywhere to find the list of status codes and what they mean. If anyone has them or knows how to help it would amazing.

Thank you.

Comment: An error like this usually comes with incompatibility between the 3 external modules one is using : selenium <-> webdriver <-> browser. Double check the versions you have deployed are compatible in pairs - mostly, the chromedriver and Chrome. It would be beneficial to add them (the versions) to the answer - someone for sure will jump in with a long post of which should be used with what (e.g. "points farming").

Comment: Thanks Todor, I have added this extra info now. I have matched the Chromium and Chromedriver. As this works on my Pi 3 B and just not on the Pi Zero W I am wondering if it something to do with the hardware.

Comment: Latest & greatest, that's good. What bothers me is the exit code "-4" - that's outside of the normal code range (0-255), and is [not defined in chromedriver](https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver/blob/master/chrome/status.h) at all (unsurprisingly, being negative). You said you moved to OS from rpi3 to the zero - do you mean you literally took the SD card out and just put it there? If so, that _might_ be the culprit -the 2 boards are with different hardware (and RAM), any compilations done during the install on the 3 may be incompatible with the zero. You'd be better of installing directly.

Comment: I have tried both. A brand new SD and a straight swap :/ both seem to get the same results and error code. Thanks for the link to the error codes I’ve been struggling to find them. I’m going to look at maybe downgrading and seeing if earlier versions work. Do you have any idea what the other chrome driver version on the Ubuntu site is? Chromedriver 34 etc? Is it a 32 bit version?

Comment: Sorry, though I have both boards, I've never used them for selenium (and I run raspbian), can't really help you.

Comment: Hold - which OS are you using on the boards? :)

Comment: Both Raspbian, latest

Comment: Have you followed these - https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=194176, and https://www.reddit.com/r/selenium/comments/7341wt/success_how_to_run_selenium_chrome_webdriver_on/

Comment: Yes, this is what got it working on my Pi3B but the same things don’t seem to be working :/ very frustrating. Thanks for the links though! I’m going to put my head down and try messing around a bit more. I’m sure it’s probably something small and simple I’m missing.

Comment: Ah I see, that’s very interesting! I’ll try and get in contact with the developers. Maybe they can shed some light on the minus. I will be sure to self answer if I get it. Thanks Todor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of looking around I have not found the meaning of the -4 code however I have found a solution for myself.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade`

As I had already updated I presume it was the upgrade that made the difference. If this does not work for you I found a big discussion and some instructions for people who had the same problem with a different application. You could follow the instructions there to see if those help. https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/4033#issuecomment-466491400

Don't forget to get the correct armhf version of chromedriver I have linked above in my question and ensure all chrome versions match. Good luck, Selenium is not easy on the Pi but it is possible.

Comment: Any other tips on installing this on a headless pi zero? Should it be able to work with an armhf chromedriver? Trying this update/upgrade now

Comment: @BrianDaneshgar Yes, I got this working. What issues are you having? The same error message?